# Copying strings containing longs

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm able to "pack" arrays of long in strings. Now, if I memcpy the string containing arrays of long, the content is lost. Here you have my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char arr[40];
    unsigned char arr2[40];
    unsigned int i = 0 ;
    long f=0;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = i + 1 ;
        *((long *)arr + i*sizeof(long)) = f ;
    }
    memcpy(arr2, arr, 40);
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = *((long *)arr2 + i*sizeof(long)) ;
        printf("f =%ld from arr2 sizeof %zu\n", f, (size_t)(i*sizeof(long)));
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = *((long *)arr + i*sizeof(long)) ;
        printf("f =%ld from arr sizeof %zu\n", f, (size_t)(i*sizeof(long)));
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
f =1 from arr2 sizeof 0
f =0 from arr2 sizeof 8
f =1 from arr2 sizeof 16
f =140734674541394 from arr2 sizeof 24
f =140734674541702 from arr2 sizeof 32
f =1 from arr sizeof 0
f =2 from arr sizeof 8
f =3 from arr sizeof 16
f =4 from arr sizeof 24
f =5 from arr sizeof 32
```

As you can see I'm able to read the long values I did store in "arr" but not from "arr2". Any clue?

Comment: `i*sizeof(long)` --> `i`

Comment: `(long *)arr2 + i*sizeof(long)` will result in undefined behavior due to out of bounds buffer access. `(long *)arr2 + i` is already indexing in `sizeof(long)`

Comment: Thank you **all** for your answers & comments. Unfortunately I can accept just one of them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `1` to pointer `p` and  `sizeof(*p) == 8`, it's equivalent to adding `8` to a `char` pointer. 
In other words, once you have cast the pointer, there's no need to scale the index anymore.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned char arr[40];
    unsigned char arr2[40];
    unsigned int i = 0 ;
    long f=0;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = i + 1 ;
        *((long *)arr + i) = f ;
    }
    memcpy(arr2, arr, 40);
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = *((long *)arr2 + i) ;
        printf("f =%ld from arr2 sizeof %zu\n", f, (size_t)(i*sizeof(long)));
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ) {
        f = *((long *)arr + i) ;
        printf("f =%ld from arr sizeof %zu\n", f, (size_t)(i*sizeof(long)));
    }
}
```

Technically though, your program is still *undefined* because it violates *strict aliasing*. You could solve that by using an array of long and accessing it via a char pointer, by using dynamic memory instead of stack-allocated arrays, or by memcpying the char bytes into a temporary long in each iteration of the loop (gcc can take the hint and the last solution doesn't end up being inefficient at all, despite what seems like a seemingly expensive function call).

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, that's what I suggested as a solution. The above program, however, does violate strict aliasing (first at `*((long *)arr + i) = f ;` ) because it's using a long pointer to access a char array, not the other way around.

Comment: Upon careful reading I am indeed mistaken. Although if a char array with automatic storage is still desired, the problem could be mitigated via union type-punning, me thinks. (trap values not withstanding of course).

Comment: @StoryTeller Sometimes I use alloca (I use it instead of VLAs because then I can still jump past the allocation) and pretend it's like malloc'd memory.

Comment: @StoryTeller Within the confines of the standard, you can get around the problem with memcpy. I've played with it, and it looks like gcc can optimize it so that such small memcpies are basically only interpreted as a nudge to suppress strict aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

`(long *)arr2 + i*sizeof(long)` will result in undefined behavior due to out of bounds buffer access. `(long *)arr2 + i` is already indexing in `sizeof(long)`.

So you write way past the end of `arr`, but copy only the first 40 bytes of it. Beyond that, there's no point reasoning about undefined behavior. Had you been lucky, it would have crashed, thus giving an immediate indication you did something terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one you cast the (decayed) pointer `arr` and `arr2` to a `long*`, then you no longer have an array ob bytes but an array of `long` so your pointer arithmetic will no longer be correct (it assumes the pointer is a pointer of `char`). Drop the multiplication, and just do e.g.

```
*((long *)arr + i) = f ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the several expressions

```
*((long *)arr + i*sizeof(long))
```

You need to decide whether you are doing the pointer arithmetic on `char` pointers, or `long` pointers.

If you want to do it on `char` pointers, you start with `arr`, add i*sizeof(long), and convert to a `long` pointer:

```
         arr
         arr + i*sizeof(long)
(long *)(arr + i*sizeof(long))
```

On the other hand, you can also convert `arr` to a `long` pointer first.  But then, you don't have to multiply by `sizeof(long)`, because arithmetic on `long` pointers works in units of `sizeof(long)`, not bytes:

```
         arr
 (long *)arr
((long *)arr + i)
```